# How to compare fields in a row in two tables and return values that are not the same

Tags: mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

properties

```
ID    Name   lastname
1     jhon   lee
2     luis   perez
3     maria  gonzales
4     jose   victoria
```

properties_ap

```
ID_ap ID    Name   lastname
10    2     manuel perez
11    4     jose   salazar
12    1     jhon   lee
13    3     maria  gonzales
```

I like to compare the row by ID an return the values that are not the same.
Example:

```
ID    Name    Name
2     Luis    manuel

ID    Lastname   Lastname
4     victoria   salazar
```

I will do the search, by individual id. so is not necessary to do a loop. 
Im using mysql and codeigniter.

I like to compare the individual row so i can see what fields are different.

Comment: what do you mean by 'same Ej'?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to write a query to do this? can you show your attempt and how the results differ from what your desired results are?

Comment: ...that are not the same, Example

Comment: Hi mike, iam a litte block here i now i can use intersect and except. but they dont exist in Mysql

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but I'm assuming you want to look for any data where the ID in the properties table matches the ID in the properties_ap table, but the first name or last name are different.  Is that correct?  If so, here's how...

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p.LastName, ap.ID, ap.Name, ap.LastName
FROM properties p
JOIN properties_ap ap
ON p.ID = ap.ID
WHERE p.Name != ap.Name OR p.LastName != ap.LastName
```

Comment: I like to compare the individual row so i can see what fields are different.

Answer (score 0):

The best SQL construct for this is `full outer join`, but MySQL doesn't support that.  Here is a way using `union all`.  It will return *both* sets of values for non-matches:

```
select which, ID, Name, Lastname
from ((select 'p' as which, ID, Name, lastname
       from properties
      ) union all
      (select 'pa' as which, ID, Name, lastname
       from properties_ap
      )
     ) p
group by id, name, lastname
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Is very good, but what if i dont wama show the field that are the same

Comment: @DiogenesChepeArdinesSalazar . . . You can't have a query where the second and third columns are sometimes `name` and sometimes `lastname`.  In that sense, you cannot do what you want with this query.  Plus, you need to specify what to do when both names are different.